# What are the pros and cons of taking the Skeleton Key?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skeleton key. Return or keep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/skeleton-key-return-or-keep)

I heard when you take the Skeleton Key you will be kicked out of the Thieves' Guild. So I want to make an objective decision on whether or not I should take it.

How does your relationship with the Thieves' Guild differ if you don't take the skeleton key vs. if you *do* take it?